# Bulk edit in Assets

Tags: assets

Is it possible to select multiple images for editing their attributes? e.g. changing keywords, date etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cem - This is not currently possible in Assets 2.  I'll be happy to send your request off to the team for consideration.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, even if there was a way to import files with their meta data would save us time.